# Single user test in Jmeter is taking more time than in browser

Tags: jmeter

I Created a script in Jmeter and tried to execute with single user and its taking around 28 minutes , where as manual browser execution of the same flow can be done in few seconds.
Below are the things I tried so far to get rid of this issue.
1. Added HTTP cookie/cache/header manager at Test plan
2. Recorded the script using HTTP Test Script Recorder
3. Used Json extractor to extract values.
4. Used 2 while loops ( but for single user it wont enter while loop)
5.Couple of response assertions are used.
6. Updated jemter.sh to use the memory 1024 to 2048 and relaunched jmeter and tried to run the same script. But still its taking 30 mins for single user
7. In HTTP request Deafualts "retrieve All embebded resources" and "paralell  downloads " = 6 are enabled
8. Jmeter properties
    #CookieManager.save.cookies=true

```
TestPlan  
Login samplers
 Action Samplers 
Logout samplers
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eszDH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHHsK.png)

Comment: I am not able to attach the .jmx file. I can post by editing in notepad if that helps to answer this

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say anything meaningful without seeing the full outline of your Test Plan (Options -> Expand All) from JMeter's main menu. However it will be much better if you could share the whole test plan either here using [Code and Preformatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) syntax or [external code-sharing solution](https://gist.github.com/discover)

If you're uncertain regarding what JMeter is doing you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter" level="debug" />
```

this way you will get **a lot of** information in the [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file.

Blind shot: you may have [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) added during recording so test is just "sleeping" on "think-times", if this is the case you can try re-running your script using `Run -> Start no pauses` option from the JMeter main menu:

[image]